# Unknown error when trying to copy data from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the following Azure Data Factory setup:

**Linked Services:**

```
"name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
"properties": {
    "description": "",
    "hubName": "***",
    "type": "AzureStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=**********;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    }
}
```

**Datasets:**

Input:

```
{
"name": "AzureBlobDatasetTemplate",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "folderPath": "app-insights/************/PageViews/{Slice}/{Hour}",
        "format": {
            "type": "JsonFormat"
        },
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "Slice",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Hour",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "HH"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 15
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
```

}

Output:

```
{
"name": "AzureTableDatasetTemplate",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureTable",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "tableName": "HelloWorld"
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 15
    }
}
```

}

**Pipeline**

```
{
"name": "PipelineTemplate",
"properties": {
    "description": "Application Insight",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BlobSource"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "AzureTableSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "AzureBlobDatasetTemplate"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "AzureTableDatasetTemplate"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "retry": 3
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "CopyActivityTemplate"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2014-05-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "datafactorypocjspi_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

}

The data in the blob storage comes from Application Insights continuous export.

My intention is for the whole setup to work like that :

1. Application Insights export the data do blob storage using the continuous export (done and working)
2. Azure Data Factory moves the data from the Blob storage to Azure Table Storage (partition and row keys will need to be calculated in that process, I haven't gotten to that part yet, since I am stuck earlier in the copy process)

With the current setup, all my activity runs are stuck in "Waiting: dataset dependencies are not ready" state:

[image: Azure pipeline activity]

The only additional information I was able to find was the state description for the activity: The upstream dependencies are not ready.

What am I missing here? It looks like it has problem connecting to the blob storage. I've double checked the connection strings, the folder path also seems to be in order:

[image: Storage Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before when provisioning time slices for large schedule windows... I think you are getting the problem because you have **15 minute** time slices for a **4 year window**!

**Dataset:**

```
"availability": {
    "frequency": "Minute",
    "interval": 15
```

**Activity:**

```
"start": "2014-05-01T00:00:00Z",
"end": "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z",
```

That's a load of provisioning ADF has to do at deployment time. The result is what you are seeing that it can't start validating upstream datasets because its still dealing with the creation of all the slices. Eg. Waiting!

It's not an ideal answer, but I my suggestion is you decrease the schedule window to something much smaller to test the copy process. Once working extend it a month at a time so the internal provisioning process has a chance to catch up.

Note; it's not just 15mins divided by 4 years. Its double that as well for each dataset. Input and output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I still have much to learn about ADF, I'd never have thought about it:) I'll change the setting tomorrow and post the update.

Comment: Ok, good luck. I would appreciate the up votes and marking the answer as accepted if this is indeed the issue. Thanks

Comment: It seems my generous date settings used up all my dev credits on Azure for March- please expect update in April, when I get new dev credits:)